# Setting a footer without GridViewCommandEventArgs in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, footer

I have a gridview.The footer has a label.Inside a function i just have to set the label..Now I don't have a `e` (GridViewCommandEventArgs) ,since its not triggered by some event.This is my code

```
`GridViewRow footer = (GridViewRow)CartGrid.FooterRow;
 Label Total = (Label)footer.FindControl("lblTotal")
 Total.Text = sum.ToString();`
```

I am getting the error -> 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

**CartGrid** is the gridview. 
 **lblTotal** is the label.
 **sum** has the content for label.

Comment: Ok I found the answer.You have to bind the grid to a data source before you set footer value.Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind the grid to a data source before you set footer value.

I have mentioned this in a comment but I was reviewing of my stalkoverflow profile and I saw this question unanswered and unclosed.So have pasted the link to the answer once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RowCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx#Y400) or [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event. For example,

```
void CartGrid_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (r.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```